# Python: Iterate through a list and only print out variables that are arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have the following example data and list:

```
data.var1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
data.var2 = 30
data.var3 = 10
allvariables = [data.var1, data.var2, data.var3]
```

Where any one of the vars could be either an array or just a number. (The data from above is just an example) I want to iterate through the allvariables list and add all the arrays to a new list.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
arrayvariables = [vname for vname, i in vars(data).items() if isinstance(i, np.ndarray)]
```

But this adds the variable name as a string to the arrayvariables list. (ex:
"var1")

I have also tried

```
arrayvariables = [vars(data).get(vname) for vname in allvariables if isinstance(vars(data).get(vname), np.ndarray)]
```

But this just adds the array value to the list. (ex: array([1, 2, 3]))

What I want is for the arrayvariables list to be the same as what the following code would create (assuming data.var1 is the only array):

```
arrayvariables = [data.var1]
```

I am fairly new to Python, so I may just be missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Any input and output would be good.

Comment: Sure, If I print the arrayvariables list from the second line of code, it results in `['var1']` Printing the arrayvariables list from the third line results in `[array([1, 2, 3])]` I've edited the main post with example variable values.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you have a list with ton of variables, and you want to loop through it and print out variables that are an array? This Code may help you

```
list_to_check = [1, 2, 5, ['another', 'list'], 10, 20]
for i in list_to_check:
    if type(i) == list: # Check if that element is a list
        print(i)
```

[Click here to see the Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vhL9.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately my array data is in a NumPy array so that code will not work as the variable type is not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define an array is an object with non-empty shape.

```
import numpy as np


a = [
    np.array(1),  # shape: ()
    np.arange(5), # shape: (5,)
    np.int(100),  # shape: ()
    np.arange(0.5, 5.5), # shape: (5,)
    5, # shape: ()
]

print(a)

r = [s for s in a if np.shape(s)]

print(r)
```

Output:

```
[array(1), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 100, array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]), 5]
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])]
```

Since you have put the variables into `allvariables`, `vars(data)` is not needed to access those variables from `data`. Simply use the following to extract array objects from `allvariables`

```
array_variables = [s for s in allvariables if np.shape(s)]
```

If you want to extract all arrays from `data`'s attributes, `vars(data)` give a dict of these attributes.

```
array_variables = [s for s in vars(data).values() if np.shape(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be almost on the answer. I believe what you are looking for is:

```py
import numpy as np

class data:
    var1: any
    var2: any
    var3: any

data.var1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
data.var2 = 30
data.var3 = 10
allvariables = [data.var1, data.var2, data.var3]

arrayvars = [v.tolist() for k, v in vars(data).items() if isinstance(v, np.ndarray)]

print(arrayvars)
```